# Can't get through Facebook app review - what can I do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-app-requests

I'm trying to get the read_insights permission on Facebook. I need it just to be able to display like counter in widget on my website.

I sent them screencast showing the like counter widget on my website. After a couple of days, they sent me this: https://screenshots.firefox.com/JRSgEeePBXLYDmFM/developers.facebook.com

I have no idea how can I show them what they want. I just want to be able to display the damn counter.

Does anyone have any idea how can I get the permissions I need? Did anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks,
Kacper

Comment: Like counter for what exactly?

Comment: My Facebook page. Here's how it looks on my website: https://screenshots.firefox.com/waLM1TuCWJaC7P31/gameshunt.pl

Answer (score 0):

```
/{page-id}?fields=fan_count
```

That´s the API call to get the current number of fans/likes. There is no need for access to insights.

For Pages you manage, you can use a Page Token of that Page. For other Pages, you need to get "[Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)" approved by Facebook.